# Iam Getting error in Interspare after upgrading mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, email

Query:

```
SELECT l.subscriberid AS subscriberid 
FROM email_list_subscribers AS l, email_queues AS q WHERE q.recipient = l.subscriberid AND q.queueid = 12 AND queuetype = 'send' AND l.listid IN (1) 
GROUP BY l.emailaddress HAVING COUNT(l.emailaddress) > 1
```

Please nay one can help me on this

Answer (score 0):

if you use “group by”, then you must use group functions in your select statement - min,max etc...

Comment: Could you please explain littile breaf?